# Understanding read built-in

Tags: shell-script, read

I'm trying to write a simple shell script for launching commands with urxvt. The idea is this (not the complete script, just the idea):

```
PRMPT="read -r CMD"
urxvt -g 55x6-20+20 -e $PRMPT
CMD
```

There are two problems with this script. The first one is that `read` is not fit for this kind of task, as it would ignore options of a command (if I write `echo hello` read would assign `echo` to `CMD` and ignore `hello`). The second one, which is the one that puzzles me most, is that `urxvt -e` exits immediately and does not wait for my input. I figure that it has to do with the fact that `read` is a builtin function, but for example `urxvt -e echo hello` works fine.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to change the script?

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: "suggestion"..: by reading the urxvt man page (which is a worthy read), one learns that like most terminal programs it essentially does whatever is designed by "-e" and when that's done it's done. sooo... if you want to run shell commands, give it a shell thusly:  urxvt -e sh -c "shell commands"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is your goal? 
echo is executable (`/bin/echo`), read is builtin. -e means execute an executable. If you wanna use a builtin function of your shell (bash?) use `urxvt -e /bin/bash -c read -r CMD`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `urxvt`, but can help you with `read`.

When you use `read` this way:

```
read -r CMD
```

It assigns the first *token* it reads to the variable `CMD`. If you want to read more tokens, you can state more variables explicitly.

```
read -r CMD ARGS1 ARG2 ARG3
```

In this case, if there are more tokens than variables to which they should be assigned, the last variable takes what it's intuitively supposed to plus the rest of the tokens read.

You can also use an array, by adding the `-a` option.

```
read -ra CMD
```

To expand an array, do:

```
"${CMD[@]}"
```

Illustration.

```
$ read -a cmd
echo ok
$ ${cmd[@]}
ok
```